# How do we read one level nested deep array data from firebase in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase database my data looks like below

[image]

my code to read data from firebase as below

```
export const startSetPartialExpenses = (() => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const uid = getState().auth.uid
        return database.ref(`users/${uid}/partialpayments`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            const partialExpenses = []
            
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                
                partialExpenses.push({
                    id: childSnapshot.key,
                    ...childSnapshot.val()
                })
            })
            dispatch(setPartialExpense(partialExpenses))
        })
    }
})
```

after reading data from firebase, It has data like below when my component initial load
[image]

Here I am copying data to local component object from redux store which is coming from the firebase database.

```
partialExpense: props.expense && props.expense.paidStatus === 'Partial Paid' ? props.partialExpense : [],
```

[image]

below I added map logic to read all the rows

```
<tbody className="create__partial-tbody">
{this.state.partialExpense.map((row) => (
<tr className="create__partial-tr" key={row.balance}>
<td>
  <select
    value={row.partialPaidStatus}
    onChange={(event) => this.handlepartialPaidStatusChange(row.balance, event)}
    >
    <option value="Select"> {`  `} </option>
    <option value="Partial Paid">Partial Paid</option>
    <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td >
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Amount"
    value={row.partialAmount}
    onChange={(event) => this.handlepartialAmountChange(row.balance, event)}
  />
</td>
```

[image]

after adding above code , I ran my code locally machine and it is not displaying my data, it is displaying default values.

[image]

Comment: `row[0].balance`

Comment: If I have multiple rows, how would I use? do I need to use array.findIndex?

Comment: if you have multiple rows, you can map the array, then get the balance of each object.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're goal is?  How do you want the data to look after you run that map?

Comment: undefined means  balance  does not exist check whether you have data inside your array

Comment: this row[0].balance worked for me.

Comment: the `map()` function has to `return` something, as it creates a new array with the values that you set in the function. So, `console.log(row.balance)` is not OK, but `return row.balance` would be. So do something like: `const balances = array.map(({ balance }) => balance)` IF `array` is the variable name that you store the response from Firebase.

Comment: None of the code you shared is reading data from Firebase, which makes it hard to correlate the code to the data you're showing. Please edit your question to show how you read the data, and how `array` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you are expecting will require two iterations, one for each key and one for each 'row'.
Since map's only work on arrays, you need to convert it to an iterable where we can also store the key should you need to update it in the future. to preserve your structure as the context of your needs is unclear, I will map it to an array of objects.

```js
const result = []
for (const [key, row] of Object.entries(data.val())) {
  for (const [index, value] of Object.entries(row)) {
    result.push({payKey: key, entry: index, ball: value.balance});
  }
}
```

from there, you should be able to manipulate the loop and code in use per your apps design.

Comment: I will update my question content with my code.

Comment: I have updated my question content with main logics and screen shots. Please let me know if that info is okay....